# Replace whole words in string

Tags: replace, words

`replace-string` has the `DELIMITED` parameter, which can be used to replace only whole words. `replace-in-string` does not have such a parameter. Is there an easy work-around besides creating a temporary buffer and using `replace-string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the function `replace-in-string`, but assuming it uses emacs regex (or using `replace-regexp-in-string`) you should be able to use word boundaries. You could match `foo` by using `\bfoo\b` (or in a string `"\\bfoo\\b"`).

For example, evaluating `(replace-regexp-in-string "\\bfoo\\b" "bar" "afoo foob foo moo")` would result in the string `"afoo foob bar moo"`.

See [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) for a detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @theldoria, here is the function:

```
(defun replace-in-string-whole-words(what with in)
  "Like 'replace-in-string, but replaces whole words."
  (replace-regexp-in-string (concat "\\b" what "\\b")  with in))
```